# How to remove a Qlabel in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I have already read some answers but they do not work for me.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):     
        cbAll = QCheckBox('Slice 1', self)              # Slice 1 
        cbAll.move(1200, 130)
        cbAll.toggle()
        cbAll.stateChanged.connect(self.OpenSlice1)

        self.setGeometry(0, 25, 1365, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Original Slices')
        self.show()


    def OpenSlice1(self,state):
        pixmap = QPixmap("E:\BEATSON_PROJECT\python\GUI\home.png") 
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)          #Qlabel used to display QPixmap
        self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.lbl.show()
        else:
            self.lbl.hide()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However when it goes into the unchecked option it does not hide the image:

Original window:
[image]

Checked Slice 1 window:
[image]

From this point on it always shows the image and I want it to hide it. i.e unckecking the box does not work:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because each time you press you are creating a new `QLabel` and you assign the same variable so you lose access to that element, and then you are closing the new `QLabel`, but not the old one. What you must do is create it and only hide it for it you could use the `setVisible()` or `hide()` and `show()` method.

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):     
        cbAll = QCheckBox('Slice 1', self)              # Slice 1 
        cbAll.move(1200, 130)
        cbAll.toggle()
        cbAll.stateChanged.connect(self.OpenSlice1)
        pixmap = QPixmap("E:\BEATSON_PROJECT\python\GUI\home.png") 
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)          #Qlabel used to display QPixmap
        self.lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setGeometry(0, 25, 1365, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Original Slices')
        self.show()

    def OpenSlice1(self, state):
        self.lbl.setVisible(state != Qt.Unchecked)
        # or
        """if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.lbl.show()
        else:
            self.lbl.hide()"""
```